# Machine learning project - my target variable is not evenly distributed in time

Tags: machine-learning

I´m working on a machine learning project where I try to predict, what clients will buy a specific product (buying the product is my target variable). I have plenty of features about the clients and enough historical data. 
My issue is that my target variable is highly seasonal – most of the product is sold in December, other months have only little sales. 
What do I have to do, to compensate this imbalance? Does the target variable need some adjustments? I need the model to have consistent performance across all months. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option would be to include month as a feature in some way. Some options for doing that:

- One-hot-encode month. Pros: very simple, leads to rather sparse features set
- Create a naive-bayes type feature encoding the prior probability of a sale in the given month. e.g. if 60% of sales are in December and uniformly 3.6% of sales in every other month, then this feature would have a value of 0.6 for every sale in December and 0.036 for sales in other months

For both of these methods you would want to ensure you have training data from a full 12 month period and separate evaluation set also from a full 12 month period.

Comment: I see, however if I add month of year as an input feature then the model will predict high probabilities only in December, isn´t that right? If we use the model in other months of year, it will likely give low probabilites. I think the model should give similar distribution of probability in every month, if that is even possible.

Comment: From your description of the problem it seems like there is a lower probability of a sale in months other than December though? Perhaps we need a clearer definition of how we define 'probability' here. Two possible definitions are :
'fraction of active customers who buy X product in month Y'
OR
'fraction of customers who visit store who buy product X in month Y'.

Because the second only considered customers who actually visit in month of interest may give more uniform probabilities?